# How to record Trail of Cthulhu spent pool points?

Tags: trail-of-cthulhu

I couldn't find any suggestion on the core rules, I was thinking on using tick marks, but it seems pretty inefficient.

Is there a better way that I'm missing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this because it's attracting one-line "here's what I do" answers without context.

Answer (score 1):

There's no set way of doing this, and when I've run it different players record it in different ways. A couple certainly did it in the same way you mention. As long as its clear, and you keep the difference between remaining points and the skill total, then you're all good.

Comment: That's what I thought. I still haven't run the game, but in a Pulp setting I could see it becoming quite a mess with all the erasing... :/

Comment: get some good erasers and you should be fine :)

Answer (score 0):

We put character sheets into a sleeve and mark spent dots with a wet erase marker.

Answer (score -1):

Magic tape on the character sheet allows for easy erasing of pencil marks without a mess. I'm not entirely sure what citations I can supply to back this up but according the Scotch website it confers the following advantages:

> Frosty on the roll, but invisible on the job. 
>   Write on it with pen, pencil or marker.